# How do I sort the values of Dropdown list and also remove the duplicate values within the Dropdown through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<select id="month" class="_5dba" title="Month" name="birthday_month" aria-label="Month">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">Mar</option>
    <option value="4">Apr</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">Jun</option>
    <option value="7">Jul</option>
    <option selected="1" value="8">Aug</option>
    <option value="9">Sept</option>
    <option value="10">Oct</option>
    <option value="11">Nov</option>
    <option value="12">Dec</option>
    <option value="13">Dec</option>
    <option value="14">Jan</option>
    <option value="15">Jun</option>
</select>
```

I want to sort by alphabetically like `Apr`,`Aug`,`Dec`..
And want to remove the repeated values like `Dec`,`Jan`,`Jun`

Once I am doing the below code i am able to read all the values in the drop-down , but not able to sort and remove duplicate values:

```
dropdownoption = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option") 
print len(dropdownoption) 
for val in dropdownoption: 
    print val.text
```

Comment: The properties of the dropdown is :<select id="month" class="_5dba" title="Month" name="birthday_month" aria-label="Month">... </select>

Comment: Once I am doing the below code i am able to read all the values in the drop-down , but not able to sort and remove duplicate values:                  dropdownoption = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option")    
             print len(dropdownoption)
             for val in dropdownoption:
                 print val.text

Comment: Can you please respect the people those who are writing the answer for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get sorted monthes without duplicates:

```
monthes = sorted(set([node.text for node in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option")]))
```

The output is

```
['Apr', 'Aug', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May', 'Month', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sept']
```

If you want to skip the first (`"Month"`) option, try to replace

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option")
```

with

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option")[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me perfectly what I was looking for.

```
dropdownoption = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option")    
print len(dropdownoption)
for val in dropdownoption:
    container=val.text
    list.append(container)
list.sort()
print ' '.join(list)
st=set(list)
print ' '.join(st)
```

Comment: Did you check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878000/how-do-i-sort-the-values-of-dropdown-list-and-also-remove-the-duplicate-values-w/51878240#51878240)? Note that 1) You're shadowing the `list` built-in function (do not call variable as `list`) 2) `sort()` performs sorting operation over existing list while `sorted()` returns sorted list on a fly (saves you 1 extra code line)

Comment: @Muddesir Did you get a chance to checkout my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878000/how-do-i-sort-the-values-of-dropdown-list-and-also-remove-the-duplicate-values-w/51878518#51878518). Let me if it looks good to you.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the values of Dropdown list and also remove the duplicate values within the Dropdown through Selenium and Python you can use the following solution:

```
months = []
sorted_months = []
unique_months = []
unique_sorted_months = []
dropdownoption = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='month']/option") 
print len(dropdownoption) 
for val in dropdownoption: 
    months.append(val.text)
print("Printing the actual list of months:")
print(months)

#Output>>>['Month', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Jun']

print("Printing the available months in sorted order:")
sorted_months = sorted(months)
print(sorted_months)

#Output>>>['Apr', 'Aug', 'Dec', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May', 'Month', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sept']

print("To remove the duplicate and print the list:")
unique_months= set(months)
print(unique_months)

#Output>>>{'May', 'Jul', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Jun', 'Jan', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Month', 'Apr', 'Dec'}

print("To remove the duplicates and print the available months in sorted order:")
unique_sorted_months = sorted(set(months))
print(unique_sorted_months)

#Output>>>['Apr', 'Aug', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'Mar', 'May', 'Month', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sept']
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect as `unique_sorted_months` are definitely not *sorted*. You can fix your code as `sorted(set(...))`, but.... this would be exactly the same solution as mine. So you can just remove your answer to not create the duplicates... Thx

Comment: Thanks @Andersson That was my bad. Corrected it.